# How to find the period of a exponential function? $5\cdot(-1)^k$

Tags: trigonometry

Currently in class we are learning Euler's formula and how it relates to imaginary numbers, exponentials, and trig functions. I know the left hand of the equation is $e^{jwt}$ and I could easily use that to transform $e$ functions but how about:

$$5\cdot(-1)^k$$

How do I apply the formula to get it into a trig function so I can find the period? Detailed explanations are preferred.

Comment: You don't need complex exponentials and trig functions to find the period. If we set $a_k = 5\cdot(-1)^k$, then how do $a_k$ and $a_{k+2}$ compare?

Comment: P.S. If you *want* to express $5\cdot(-1)^k$ in terms of complex exponentials, then note that $-1 = e^{i\pi}$, so $(-1)^k = e^{i \pi k}$.

Comment: So then 2 would be the fundamental period? Since if we let k be 1 you get -5 for both and thus it repeats. Thanks for the answer, but how do I find it in general do you just think about it or is there a specific formula. I mean how did you think about using a_k and a_(k+2) to get the period?

Comment: Did you get that from Euler's identity? and how come you could just raise both sides by k? I understand the representation, but I don't see how you could just raise it by k. I guess if it's valid algebraically it's okay to do so? :)

Comment: Yes, 2 is the fundamental period. $(-1)^k$ is a special case where it's easy to see the period, because you recognize that it oscillates back and forth between $-1$ and $1$. In general, if you have an expression of the form $e^{2\pi i k / K}$ then the period is $K$. In this case, $(-1)^k = e^{\pi i k} = e^{2\pi i k / 2}$, so the period is $K = 2$.

Comment: Typically, Bungo. Is it difficult to find periods of functions that are non-trigonmetric? I mean I could imagine even tougher ones. Just curious. This is an electrical engineering course I'm taking.

Comment: Yes, you can get $-1 = e^{i\pi}$ from Euler's identity, since $e^{i\pi} = \cos(\pi) + i \sin(\pi) = -1 + i \cdot 0 = -1$. Then if we take the $k$th power of both sides, we get $(-1)^k = (e^{i\pi})^k = e^{i \pi k}$ where the last equality follows because in general, $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.

Comment: @Bungo I feel I should add that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ doesn't hold for all complex numbers (as TwilightSparkle seems to know) but it does work here.

Comment: For non-trigonometric functions, or in general, you can always try writing $f(x + T) = f(x)$ [in other words, plug in $x+T$ into the formula for $f(x)$], and see if you can solve for $T$. The smallest positive $T$ that satisfies $f(x+T) = f(x)$ is the period.

Comment: @EulCan: Yes, thanks for that clarification.

Comment: Exactly that's what I meant it doesn't hold for all complex numbers that's why I asked. Also Bungo, thanks for answering my question. I have seen that technique with f(x) = f(x+T). You just have to find the smallest value T for which the equality holds, correct? Also I'm assuming  that if we can't find that said T (through algebra) then the function is non-periodic.